How to access openstack api using idp provider (for eg.- zitadel or keyclock) access token?
when i try to access openstack api using zitadel access token, it gives a 401 unauthentiction.
I setup a openstack federation and websso using openid connect in devstack and i can login using keyclock but when i try to use keyclock access token to access openstack api, it always throw a 401 unauthorized. So what are the solution regarding it so i can access openstack api like servers, networks, volumes etc uisng keyclock access token?. It will be helpful if someone give a any solution or hint regarding it?

How are you retrieving the keystone token? How are you using that token to access to the openstack api? Please show us your code.

i have not been able to retrieve any keystone token. I tried to generate keystone token using access token but i am unable to do it.  POST {keystone-url}/v3/OS-FEDERATION/identity_providers/keystone/protocols/keyclock/auth Header {Authorization: Bearer {Keyclock_Access_Token}}

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
